# Get value from STDClass

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, stdclass

I'm using PHP and CodeIgniter.
I ran a query using the following script:

```
$query = $this->db->query('select login_id, date_created from prjsite_login');
$row = $query->result();
print_r($row);
```

The result of the print_r is:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [login_id] => admin [date_created] =>
>   2018-04-04 13:18:42 ) )

Which is correct. Thou when I tried to fetch 1 object or value from stdClass using the following script:

```
echo $query->login_id;
```

I received an error below:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: pages/home.php
>
> Line Number: 21
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\BMI_PRJSITE\application\views\pages\home.php
>   Line: 21 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\BMI_PRJSITE\application\controllers\Pages.php
>   Line: 11 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\BMI_PRJSITE\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: Your variable is called `$row` and you're trying to access `$query`. Looks like a typo to me. `$row` also appears to be an array, not just a single object.

Comment: really ? have you try to debug yourself ?

Comment: Apologies, i posted a wrong variable since i was debugging it but using $row returns same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly get a value from $query because at this point you are just generating a query and you will get the result from $query only after executing it which you are doing at

```
$row=$query->result();
```

Looking at your result you are getting a result as an array of a stdClass object so need to json-encode your object and then decode it back to an array

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($row), True);
```

If you are sure you will get only one row then no need for loop and you can simply do it by

```
echo $array[0]->login_id;
```

otherwise, you have to go for a loop

```
 foreach ($array as  $value) {
        echo $value->login_id;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As your result is in array and array contain object your have to first access that array then object

```
echo $row[0]->login_id;
```

Or use `foeach` to get all values

```
foreach($row as $value)
{
    echo $value->login_id;
}
```